# How can I force to launch my programm to use only one NUMA-node0 when it possible?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, numa

I have a server with 2xCPU-Socket Intel Xeon.

On Ubuntu 14.04 TLS for 36 total cores = (2 x CPUs x 9 Cores x 2 HyperThreading), lscpu give me:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                36
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-35
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    9
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 63
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               1200.000
BogoMIPS:              5858.45
Hypervisor vendor:     Xen
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              25600K
```

-

```
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-8,18-26
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     9-17,27-35
```

Two last lines means that if I launch more than 9 threads, for example, 12 threads, then 9 threads (0-8) will execute on the 1st CPU (NUMA **node0**) and 3 threads (9-12) on the 2nd CPU (NUMA **node1**).

If I use this `numactl –localalloc --physcpubind=0-8,18-26 ./myprogram` then my program can use only one NUMA-node0 even if number of threads more than 18: https://linux.die.net/man/8/numactl

But I want to use only one NUMA-node0 when it's possible, and more when it's needed. How can I force to launch my programm's threads at first on 0-17 Cores, and only if number of threads more than 18 then on 18-35 Cores?

Can I use for this as bellow?

1. `numactl –localalloc --physcpubind=0-8,18-26,9-17,27-35 ./myprogram`
2. `numactl --localalloc --cpunodebind=0,1 ./myprogram`

Comment: This sounds like a X-Y problem. Is there a particular reason for this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @user3528438 Using the HyperThreading's threads (18-26) increases performance more than using the 2nd CPU-NUMA-node1 threads (9-17) for my software, which is QPI-bounded.

Comment: Interesting. No way to make it less so?

Comment: If you're writing a program yourself, you could use libnuma or more cleaner DPDK to choose how and which cores are used. :) Just a suggestion.